# how to post a json file using curl in docker file for the container

Tags: docker

I have created a baseDocker https://github.com/streamsets/datacollector-docker image .
Now as per entry-point it restarts the stream sets data collector.

So, now I have created another child dockerfile based on this above base image where I have copied lots of pipeline related libs(this is not the issue). Now at the end of this child dockerfile, I have to post a pipeline using curl.  In this child dockerfile, I have copied the pipeline to /tmp folder.

my question is how to post a json [pipeline](https://gist.github.com/tdonovic/2594a0fb0d3fb2d21a8756d28c123cf7) using CURL in the child dockerfile. Knowing that streamsets has been running from the base.

so, my shell script looks like this

```
curl --noproxy localhost:18631 --insecure --silent --request POST http://localhost:18631/rest/v1/pipeline/test/import" --user xxx:xxxx --data-binary @/tmp/pipeline.json" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header  "X-Requested-By:sdc" --write-out "%{http_code}" --output /tmp/sdc-pipeline-response.json
```

Comment: In a Dockerfile _nothing_ is running.  Any process that might have been started in a `RUN` command gets stopped at the end of that line.  Your entrypoint script doesn't restart a process because it wasn't running before, it starts it for the first time (after `docker build` is complete, when you `docker run` the image).

Comment: so, what are you suggesting?

Comment: Is there some other way to load data into the application?  Or, can you run a script outside the container to do this import?  The way Docker is set up the workflow you're describing is tricky (you need to start the server as a background job, run this import command, stop the background job, then restart the server as the main container process).

Comment: i was thinking the same, I will post it as soon as If it works. thanks.